# AIR 32, AS3, Animate CC IDE, Worker NOT AT ALL working :(

Tags: actionscript-3, air, worker

I have been working on this for more than 6 hours now, not been able to find out what is wrong. I would like to run some check in the background and hence wanted to deploy a background worker in AIR (32.0) AS3 (Animate CC 2018 IDE).

I have already tried 2-3 examples but I do not know why the background worker is not responding, I tried building the package, and installing the package but the bg worker does not start. .state says it is working but I cannot see any result (tried to create a txt file in desktop within bg worker, even had kept run=time error but absolutely nothing happens).

I am simply trying to copy what adobe docs says but nothing happens. Created 3 classes (copy-paste) and run the code, built the app but not working.

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Worker.html#state

Anyone can help? I have already built the app which checks for some background details and for roughly 8 to 10 seconds, the app freezes - that too on a workstation.

Comment: I worked with **Worker**s and they worked (ugh, pun unintended) just fine. There are a few things though. First, **WorkerDomain.createWorker(...)** has a second argument which is **false** by default, but if you want the background thread be able to interact with the environment rather than with the main app only, you should elevate that to **true**. Then, it only grants as much permissions as the main application could have, so you need to put those into the app manifest and **requestPermission** them if applicable.

Comment: I tried that as well, but nothing works. I do not need any permission other than checking some local files. Were you able to see the trace statements sent by background worker during development in output window?

Comment: No, I don't think, **trace** is available from **Worker**. Exception handling as well. I think I had to devise two shared **ByteArray** buffers to pass commands and fetch feedback from **Worker** thread, and that's how I debugged what's going on inside there.

Comment: You might also want to read and try this: https://forum.starling-framework.org/d/16481-easy-as-worker-api-to-manage-workers-in-adobe-air

Comment: That looks promising, will definitely give it a try after weekend, thanks a lot

Comment: You should add a [mcve] to your question so we can provide code as a solution.